# Expected ')' to complete '#selector' expression

Tags: swift, xcode

I get the error, **Expected ')' to complete '#selector' expression** in the code below:

```
    let dismissKeyboard = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CreateRoomsViewController.dismissKeyboard(_):)))
    dismissKeyboard.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(dismissKeyboard)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func dismissKeyboard(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: remove 1 ")" at the end

Comment: Check your brackets, it is stated clearly.  `let dismissKeyboard = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CreateRoomsViewController.dismissKeyboard(_ :)))`

Comment: I did that but now I got 8 errors

Comment: thanks for the help everyone! coding in: #selector(CreateRoomsViewController.dismissKeyboard(tap:))) was the solution for me!

Comment: Comment the line, start rewriting it and let XCode autcomplete helps you.

Comment: thanks for the late answer! but I solved the problem with the help from fusing the code answers from 2 of the peoples comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#selector(CreateRoomsViewController.dismissKeyboard(_):)
```

Needs to be:

```
#selector(CreateRoomsViewController.dismissKeyboard(tap:)
```

Besides the extra `)` you can’t use `(_:)` because your parameter has a label of `tap`.

Even easier is:

```
#selector(dismissKeyboard)
```

And you need to add `@obj` in front of the method.

Comment: I tried those 2 methods but got some more errors, but coding in #selector(CreateRoomsViewController.dismissKeyboard(tap:))) instead worked!

Comment: You got error because you don't have @objc in you func. Edit to `@objc func dismissKeyboard(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```html
  let dismissKeyboard = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
    dismissKeyboard.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(dismissKeyboard)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }
 @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
 }
 }
```

Comment: thanks you for the late reply! but I already solved the error :D

Comment: You don’t need the `self.` in the selector.